# How to replace NULL with empty string in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using below query to fetch column value by comma separated.

```
    (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT  ',' + CAST(Proj_ID AS VARCHAR) FROM PROJECT
    left join dbo.PROJ_STA on
    Project.PROJ_STA_ID = Project.PROJ_STA_ID
    WHERE ENTER_DT < DATEADD(Year, -7, GETDATE())  AND PROJ_LFCYC_STA_CD = 'A' AND 
    PROJ_STA.PROJ_STA_DS = 'Cancelled' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
    AS Enter_Date)
```

Can anyone guide me to replace null value by empty string here.

Updated:

```
    (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT  ',' + coalesce( CAST(Proj_ID AS VARCHAR), '' ) FROM PROJECT
    left join dbo.PROJ_STA on
    Project.PROJ_STA_ID = Project.PROJ_STA_ID
    WHERE ENTER_DT < DATEADD(Year, -7, GETDATE())  AND PROJ_LFCYC_STA_CD = 'A' AND 
    PROJ_STA.PROJ_STA_DS = 'Cancelled' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
    AS Enter_Date)
```

Comment: What is Proj_ID? an int?

Comment: Yes But since i am separatin it by comma, i used it as Varchar

Comment: Try - select ',' + convert(varchar,coalesce(Proj_ID, ''))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `IsNull`

```
select ISNULL(Column,'') as ColumnName
```

OR `COALESCE`

```
select COALESCE(NULLIF(ColumnName,''), 'Column')
```

Comment: Try `IFNULL(columnName, '')`

Answer (score 4):

An example from the AdventureWorks database

```
select e.ModifiedDate, ISNULL(p.FirstName,'') as FirstName
from Person.BusinessEntity as e 
    left join Person.Person as p on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
```

By using this, if there are no matching Person records, the FirstName will be displayed as an empty string instead of NULL

Answer (score 2):

You can white out null values with the [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function

```
select coalesce(MyColumn, '')
```

Coalesce takes any number of columns or constants and returns the first one which isn't null.

Your query would be:

```
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT  ',' + convert(varchar, coalesce( Proj_ID, '' )) FROM PROJECT
left join dbo.PROJ_STA on
Project.PROJ_STA_ID = Project.PROJ_STA_ID
WHERE ENTER_DT < DATEADD(Year, -7, GETDATE())  AND PROJ_LFCYC_STA_CD = 'A' AND 
PROJ_STA.PROJ_STA_DS = 'Cancelled' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
AS Enter_Date)
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am still getting null value if i use coalsec or isnull in my query.

Comment: If you've already tried with coalesce and IsNull can you show the version with it not working? It's much more likely to be an issue with your query than the functions themselves!

Comment: @saravanakumarr a schema would be handy too!

Comment: Sure, pls refer updated question...I am not getting error. I am getting null value again.

Comment: Still i am getting Null Value.

Comment: You need to strip back your query then and put it together in stages. What happens if you take out the where clauses? What happens if you take out the converts and the concatenation? Pull it back to a one line query and build it up an element at a time