# Replace NULL with empty string in SQL for ALL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

These questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21233442/1366033), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12394545/1366033), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244808/1366033)) all identified how to return an empty string instead of `NULL` *for a single column*:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ColA,'') AS ColA FROM Table1
```

However, I have a query that returns a whole bunch of columns that I'm too lazy to select individually (don't worry - this isn't a production query)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Is there a way to return an empty string for all columns returned by the wildcard operator?

For Example, the following naive attempt *won't work*:

```
SELECT ISNull(*,'') FROM Table1
```

Comment: not without using dynamic SQL, and even then, you'll need to first check what data type every column has

Comment: Depending on the number of columns and/or whether or not they are the same data type your best bets are probably to either generate the statement by selecting against INFORMATION_SCHEMA or use a text editor with good macro capabilities.

Comment: "I'm too lazy"  There are no good technical solutions to people problems.  I suggest getting a query analyzer that will populate your column names for you.

Comment: Use the sys.columns view to help you build your sql.

Comment: @TomH, Yeah, I'm leaning toward selecting the table and then doing a regex find and replace for [`\[.*\]` and replacing with `ISNULL($&,'') AS $&`](http://regexr.com/3cqov).  Was just hopeful that there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this to generate a SQL query string in order to execute it dynamically, check if this works for you:

```
;WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT 'ISNULL(' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + 
  CASE 
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bit' THEN '0'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN '0'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' THEN '0'
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'date' THEN '''1/1/1900'''
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' THEN '''1/1/1900'''
    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier' THEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    ELSE '''''' 
  END + ') AS ' + COLUMN_NAME AS columnNameIsNull 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
)

SELECT
stuff((
    SELECT ( ', ' + columnNameIsNull )
                       FROM cte
                        FOR XML PATH( '' )
                    ), 1, 1, '' ) AS string
```

Answer (score 0):

Why write complicated dynamic SQL queries if you can just use Column Select (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+Click+drag) to [perform a multiline select in your query editor](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/select-text-vertically-in-microsoft-word/)?

This way, you can type `ISNULL(`... once for all your columns. Just make sure the columns are aligned and you should be good to go. Supported as of SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Otherwise just use Notepad++.

Comment: I don't think the dynamic query is as elegant as I was hoping for, but column select has issues as well. The problem is that once you perform a calculation on a field (using `ISNULL`) then SQL drops the column name. So you'd need to update `ColA` to `ISNULL(ColA,'') AS ColA`, which is hard for multiline select. For manual fixing, I'd rather just do a [find and replace with the reqex query in my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462467/replace-null-with-empty-string-in-sql-for-all-columns#comment58621482_35462467)

Comment: That is why I alwasy write my queries as Alias = ISNULL(ColA, ColB)

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate the SQL needed to replace all blank values with NULL values in ALL columns of a schema.table

Just copy the output into a new Query window and run.

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100) = N'YourTableName'
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(100) = N'YourSchemaName'

SELECT 'UPDATE ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = NULL WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''''' AS UpdateSQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Refined @SEMICS Post and added execution of the result

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100) = N'YourTableName'
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(100) = N'YourSchemaName'
DECLARE @val varchar(max)

SELECT @val = COALESCE(@val + 'UPDATE ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = NULL WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''''' + '; ','')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND C.DATA_TYPE like '%CHAR%'

EXEC (@val);
```